# Run selenium tests in docker container

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, jenkins, docker

I want to build a docker image from the sources of my javascript project. I wrote some tests with the Mocha Framework. The tests should run during the build docker build process because I want to automate the build with Jenkins.

The tests should use the Firefox webdriver. I installed Xvfb in the docker image to provide a virtual display for the Firefox process.

But everytime I run the build all tests fail and I get error messages like the following:

```
Uncaught WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response: {"error":"unknown error","message":"connection refused"}
  at WebDriverError (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
  at client_.send.then.response (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:477:17)
  at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
  at TaskQueue.execute_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
  at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
  at asyncRun (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2820:25)
  at node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
  at Function.createSession (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:329:24)
  at Driver (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js:386:38)
  at Builder.build (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:467:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (test/e2e/driver.js:10:69)
...
```

When I run the tests outside of the docker container on my local machine everything works fine.

I initialize the webdriver with the following commands:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var capabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.firefox();
capabilities.set('marionette', true);
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(capabilities).build();
```

Are there any best practices on how to run selenium tests headlessly inside of a docker container?

Comment: Could you add the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by running the gulp task that starts the selenium-standalone server and the tests with xvfb-run:

```
CMD xvfb-run ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js test
```